# approximating log10[x^k0 + k1]

Tags: optimization, math, sse, simd, approximation

Greetings. I'm trying to approximate the function

Log10[x^k0 + k1], where .21 < k0 < 21, 0 < k1 < ~2000, and x is integer < 2^14.

k0 & k1 are constant. For practical purposes, you can assume k0 = 2.12, k1 = 2660. The desired accuracy is 5*10^-4 relative error.

This function is virtually identical to Log[x], except near 0, where it differs a lot.

I already have came up with a SIMD implementation that is ~1.15x faster than a simple lookup table, but would like to improve it if possible, which I think is very hard due to lack of efficient instructions.

My SIMD implementation uses 16bit fixed point arithmetic to evaluate a 3rd degree polynomial (I use least squares fit). The polynomial uses different coefficients for different input ranges. There are 8 ranges, and range i spans (64)2^i to (64)2^(i + 1).
The rational behind this is the derivatives of Log[x] drop rapidly with x, meaning a polynomial will fit it more accurately since polynomials are an exact fit for functions that have a derivative of 0 beyond a certain order.

SIMD table lookups are done very efficiently with a single _mm_shuffle_epi8(). I use SSE's float to int conversion to get the exponent and significand used for the fixed point approximation. I also software pipelined the loop to get ~1.25x speedup, so further code optimizations are probably unlikely.

What I'm asking is if there's a more efficient approximation at a higher level?
For example:

1. Can this function be decomposed into functions with a limited domain like
   log2((2^x) * significand) = x + log2(significand)

hence eliminating the need to deal with different ranges (table lookups). The main problem I think is adding the k1 term kills all those nice log properties that we know and love, making it not possible. Or is it?

1. Iterative method? don't think so because the Newton method for log[x] is already a complicated expression
2. Exploiting locality of neighboring pixels? - if the range of the 8 inputs fall in the same approximation range, then I can look up a single coefficient, instead of looking up separate coefficients for each element. Thus, I can use this as a fast common case, and use a slower, general code path when it isn't. But for my data, the range needs to be ~2000 before this property hold 70% of the time, which doesn't seem to make this method competitive.

Please, give me some opinion, especially if you're an applied mathematician, even if you say it can't be done. Thanks.

Comment: Those voting to close, and thus thinking Numerical Methods are not a programming topic should abide by Knuth judgment in afterlife.

Comment: What kind of accuracy are you getting, and what accuracy do you need?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to state the accuracy. I'm not certain, but I think a relative error <= 0.0005 is desired.

Comment: You can try using Taylor series to get a polynomial approximation. However derivatives would have to be computed in x=1 because of fractional k0 which makes derivatives in x=0 undefined.

Comment: No, that's a bad idea. Taylor series only use *local* information and can be a very bad global fit. Just think about fitting abs(x) with Taylor series.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to improve on least-squares fitting by using [Chebyshev approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Chebyshev_approximation). (The idea is, you're looking for the approximation whose worst-case deviation in a range is least; least-squares instead looks for the one whose summed squared difference is least.) I would guess this doesn't make a huge difference for your problem, but I'm not sure -- hopefully it could reduce the number of ranges you need to split into, somewhat.

If there's already a fast implementation of `log(x)`, maybe compute `P(x) * log(x)` where P(x) is a polynomial chosen by Chebyshev approximation. (Instead of trying to do the whole function as a polynomial approx -- to need less range-reduction.)

I'm an amateur here -- just dipping my toe in as there aren't a lot of answers already.

Answer (score 2):

One observation:
You can find an expression for how large x needs to be as a function of k0 and k1, such that the term x^k0 dominates k1 enough for the approximation:

x^k0 +k1 ~= x^k0, allowing you to approximately evaluate the function as

k0*Log(x).

This would take care of all x's above some value.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read how the sRGB model compresses physical tri stimulus values into stored RGB values.

It basically is very similar to the function I try to approximate, except that it's defined piece wise:

k0 x,              x < 0.0031308

k1 x^0.417 - k2      otherwise

I was told the constant addition in Log[x^k0 + k1] was to make the beginning of the function more linear. But that can easily be achieved with a piece wise approximation. That would make the approximation a lot more "uniform" - with only 2 approximation ranges. This should be cheaper to compute due to no longer needing to compute an approximation range index (integer log) and doing SIMD coefficient lookup.

For now, I conclude this will be the best approach, even though it doesn't approximate the function precisely. The hard part will be proposing this change and convincing people to use it.